# Analysis of the completeness of the availability of products from the ClickHouse SQL database

Tags: mysql, sql, data-analysis, clickhouse

Documentation: https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/

Goal: 85% of the brand's product range should be available for purchase

1. Calculate the number of products of each brand by availability (maxItems > 0)
2. Make a breakdown of brands by the availability of the assortment to purchase:

- Green: > 85%
- Yellow: 70-84%
- Red: 0-69%

1. Done:

```
SELECT brand, COUNT(1) AS cnt
    FROM products
        WHERE maxItems > 0
    GROUP BY brand
    ORDER BY cnt DESC;
```

Ok.

2. Below is an example to solve:

Each brand has an assortment, but it is not all available, but only some %.
You need to calculate this percentage for each brand using the formula:

(Number of all products (id) - The number of products that are not available (maxItems = 0)) / count(id) * 100% = result %

Below is an example of the request:

```
SELECT brand, 
    (((SELECT COUNT(1) FROM products) -
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM products WHERE maxItems = 0)) / 
    (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM products) * 100) as cnt
    FROM products
        WHERE cnt > 85
    GROUP BY brand
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
    LIMIT 1000;
```

Result:

```
brand   cnt
Amorem  99.27102236131287
VALENS  99.27102236131287
FARFAL  99.27102236131287
VIAILA  99.27102236131287
4Kids   99.27102236131287
```

What should I fix in the code to count the percentage only by brand?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT brand, (count() - countIf(maxItems = 0)) / count() * 100 as cnt
    FROM products
    GROUP BY brand
    HAVING cnt > 85
    ORDER BY cnt DESC
    LIMIT 1000;
```

Comment: Thank you, just what need! :)